# Trying to create an instance of a custom type from List<string>. Both inherit from System.Collections.Generic.List<string>

Tags: c#, string, list, collections

I have a 3rd party web API that uses a custom type called ArrayOfString which inherits from System.Collections.Generic.List. I'm trying to write method that will generate a List dynamically and return an ArrayOfString however, I have not been able to figure out how to do it correctly.

```
// Definition of ArrayOfString in API
public class ArrayOfString : System.Collections.Generic.List<string> {}


// Working Example with Static elements
public ArrayOfString GetPropertiesAsArrayOfString()
{
  ArrayOfString properties = new ArrayOfString()
  {
    "Name|String",
    "Description|String",  
    "InventoryLevel|Int32", 
    "Sku|String", 
    "UpdatedAt|DateTime" 
  };

  return properties;
}


// Trying to initialize the ArrayofString from a collection instead of from static strings. 

// Dynamically generated List<string>
List<string> items = new List<string>() { "Name|String", "Description|String", ect... };

ArrayOfString properties = new ArrayOfString(items)
```

The above code gives an error stating the ArrayOfString does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments which makes sense however I'm not sure how else to initialize the custom type. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If they have a working example, why don't you follow it? It is showing you the collection initialization syntax that C# supports. Otherwise, use Add to one item or AddRange to add multiple items at once. It gets those methods via the List<string> base class. Use them.

Comment: If it is really an Array, that it makes sense that it won't work. A list is not the same as an array, maybe they just picked the IList interface as a convenience. If the Array has an AddRange method that could work aswell. Otherwise check if it has a constructor which sets the "size" of the array, and then just do a loop over your array and set the fields in the array by hand, 3 lines of code.

Comment: Many thanks. The AddRange method worked. I am using a method in a base class to map public property names and types to table columns and it seemed like it would be a much more elegant solution than setting static values in each class. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to leave the question as unanswered. 
My final base class that I developed looks like this.

Thanks again for your help.

```
public class BaseType
{
  public ArrayOfString GetPropertiesAsArrayOfString(Type type)
  {
    PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = type.GetProperties();
    List<string> items = new List<string>();
    string propertyType = string.empty;

    for (int x = 0; x < propertyInfos.count(); x++)
    {

      switch propertyInfos[x].PropertyType.ToString())
      {
        case "System.String":
             propertyType = "String";
             break;
        case "System.DataTime":
             propertyType = "DateTime";
             break;
        case "System.Int32":
             propertyType = "Int32";
             break;
      }

      items.Add(propertyInfos[x].Name + "|" + propertyType);
    }

    ArrayOfString properties = new ArrayOfString();
    properties.AddRange(items);
    return properties
  }
}
```